# Ubuntu 14.04 Freezes

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, freeze

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit on my PC. After I've installed nVidia drivers (recommended) to solve the problem of the cursor that vanishes, Ubuntu freezes randomly when I'm working, I mean that the system doesn't react to my actions.

System Config are :

Sony F Series, GeForce GT 740M/PCIe/SSE2, Intel Core i5-3337U CPU@1.80GHz×4, RAM 8gb

I think there is the issue with my graphic card.
I am presently using "NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.113 from nvidia" as my graphics card driver.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Ubuntu NVidia drivers generate some problems on slightly older *and* slightly newer NVidia hardware.

If you want *more* then the standard Ubuntu repository drivers, install the [xorg.edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA.  As the xorg.edgers group ask not to give installation instructions directly without linking to their page, this is the best I can do *for now...*

If you don't know what a PPA is or need some guidance about rolling forward and backward of driver versions after reading their page, leave a comment below.